# Edit related child records in lightning record form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-record-form, childrecords

I have a requirement to display and edit related opportunity records of parent account. I am trying this requirement using apex and lightning record form, but no data is getting displayed.

Please let me know if it is possible to show and edit related records using record form.

Thanks

Apex class:

```
public with sharing class relatedOpp_Account {


    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> displayRelatedOpp_Account(string accId ) {

        return [select id, name, stagename, amount, accountId from opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];
    }}
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import displayRelatedOpp_Account from '@salesforce/apex/relatedOpp_Account.displayRelatedOpp_Account';

import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';
import STAGENAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';
import AMOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Amount';

const COLS = [
    {
        label: 'Opportunity Name',
        fieldName: NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName,
        editable: false
    },
    {
        label: 'Stage Name',
        fieldName: STAGENAME_FIELD.fieldApiName,
        editable: true,
        
    },
    { 
        label: 'Amount', 
        fieldName: AMOUNT_FIELD.fieldApiName, 
        editable: true 
    }
];

export default class RelatedRec_RecordForm extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    
    @api opps=[];
    columns = COLS;

    @wire(displayRelatedOpp_Account, { accId: '$recordId' })
    wiredOpps ({error, data})
    {
        
        if (error)
        {
            this.opps = undefined;
            
        }
        else if (data)
        {
            this.opps = data;
        }
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>

        <template if:true={opps.data}>

            <lightning-record-form
                    record-id={recordId}
                    object-api-name={objectApiName}
                    fields={columns}
                    columns="2"
                    mode="view"
                    onsubmit={handleSubmit}
>
            </lightning-record-form>

        </template>

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@api opps=[];
```

As I've said before, `@api` makes this read-only. Do not use the `@api` decorator unless you are exposing a public property to be set by a parent component or other special mechanism (e.g. `@api recordId` to add record-aware context).

---

```
<template if:true={opps.data}>
```

This only works if you have a wire property, and not a wire function. Also, `if:true` is deprecated, use `lwc:if`. Change your code to:

```
<template lwc:if={opps}>
```

Since you intend to edit your data, you'll need to copy your data.

```
opps;
@wire(displayRelatedOpp_Account, { accId: '$recordId' })
wiredOpps({data, error}) {
  this.opps = data && data.map((opp)=>({...opp}));
}
```

---

Datatable supports creating [custom data types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_table_custom_types). I am not going to write out the full solution, but in summation, you can create a new data type called `picklist` that would allow you to create a dropdown within `lightning-datatable`, which would solve your problem.

If you decided you wanted to go with `lightning-record-edit-form`, note that you should avoid using these forms in bulk to mass load or mass submit records. You will experience extreme delays if you have more than a handful of records being edited at once. Also, you won't have an easy way to determine which records have been edited without writing more code, unlike `lightning-datatable`, so you'll be updating records unnecessarily if you're not careful. You'd have to write more Apex code to support saving the records, which you'll have to do with `lightning-datatable` anyways.

Using `lightning-datatable` to bulk edit is the correct method. You just need to add a custom data type, and write the logic to save the records from the `draftValues` property of `lightning-datatable`.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

The code provided is using a Lightning Web Component to display related opportunity records of a parent account using a record form. However, there are a few issues with the code that need to be addressed to achieve the desired functionality.

The Apex method displayRelatedOpp_Account is returning a list of opportunities but the Lightning record form is expecting fields as an array of objects. You need to modify the Apex method to return the required fields.

The columns property in the record form is referring to the fields array, which is not defined. Instead, you should use the cols array that is defined earlier.

The editable property of the COLS array is not being used in the record form. To make the fields editable, you need to set the mode property of the record form to edit.

Here's the modified code that should work:

Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class relatedOpp_Account {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Map<String, Object>> displayRelatedOpp_Account(string accId) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> oppList = new List<Map<String, Object>>();
        List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id, Name, StageName, Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :accId];
        for (Opportunity opp : opps) {
            Map<String, Object> oppMap = new Map<String, Object>();
            oppMap.put('Id', opp.Id);
            oppMap.put('Name', opp.Name);
            oppMap.put('StageName', opp.StageName);
            oppMap.put('Amount', opp.Amount);
            oppList.add(oppMap);
        }
        return oppList;
    }
}
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import displayRelatedOpp_Account from '@salesforce/apex/relatedOpp_Account.displayRelatedOpp_Account';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';
import STAGENAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';
import AMOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Amount';

const COLS = [
    {
        label: 'Opportunity Name',
        fieldName: NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName,
        editable: false
    },
    {
        label: 'Stage Name',
        fieldName: STAGENAME_FIELD.fieldApiName,
        editable: true,
    },
    { 
        label: 'Amount', 
        fieldName: AMOUNT_FIELD.fieldApiName, 
        editable: true 
    }
];

export default class RelatedRec_RecordForm extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName = 'Opportunity';
    @api opps = [];
    cols = COLS;

    @wire(displayRelatedOpp_Account, { accId: '$recordId' })
    wiredOpps ({error, data}) {
        if (error) {
            this.opps = undefined;
            const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error',
                message: error.body.message,
                variant: 'error'
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } else if (data) {
            this.opps = data;
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-form').submit(fields);
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Opportunities">
        <template if:true={opps.data}>
            <lightning-record-form
                record-id={recordId}
                object-api-name={objectApiName}
                fields={cols}
            columns="2"
            mode="edit"
            onsubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
        </lightning-record-form>
    </template>
    <template if:true={opps.error}>
        <p>{opps.error}</p>
    </template>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

In the HTML template, the Lightning record form is now using the cols array to define the fields and the mode property is set to "edit" to make the fields editable.

The handleSubmit function has also been added to submit the form when the user saves the changes.

Finally, an error message is displayed if there is an error fetching the related opportunities.

You can make any changes if required.

Comment: How is this different that what OP already has? Why do you think it should work? Please [edit] your answer to add that so this isn't just a code dump. The explanation is as important as the solution.

Comment: This code will not work as written, and so lacking an explanation, this answer likely won't be of much help.

Comment: I don't want datatable here. I have already implemented this POC using datatable, but I have one field which is a picklist type., which is not supported by datatble. For this reason, I wanted to shift towards something simpler like record-form, but I'm not sure if record-form has the capability to display child records too.

Comment: Oh Sorry. Here i have updated my answer.

Comment: Can you please check if your code is working? It's not working for me.Error during LWC component connect phase: [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')]

Comment: I don't get any error, but this code doesn't display the form.
Sorry the previous code will not work because In the given code, you are trying to display a list of related Opportunities for a particular Account, and you want to edit the Stage Name and Amount fields for each opportunity using the lightning-record-form component. However, the lightning-record-form component does not support editing multiple records at once.
you have to use data table to achieve this.